# Got “page isn't redirecting properly” issue In mod_jk clustering

Tags: httpd, jboss, failovercluster

I have installed two jboss AS 7 servers on two different machines and i start these two by switching standalone-ha.xml configuration. Also i installed an apache httpd server in one of theses machine and i configured and install mod_jk module to the apache httpd server. Then i configured the clustering of the jboss servers with the httpd server [according to this documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/GTNPORTAL36/Clustering+configuration).

The problem is i got The page isn't redirecting properly error when i request the apache httpd servers configured url in the case of the **both jboss servers are running**. But if i turn off any one of the jboss servers (node) i got the application by requesting the apache httpd server configured url.